# How to configure TortoiseGit for Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, tortoisegit

We are using Gerrit. We have Windows users which are not familiar with Git (commands), so i am trying to configure TortoiseGit as GUI.

1. generate .ppk and public rsa openssh using Puttygen
2. copy and paste public key in gerrit users profile under sshkey, and try to clone repo but occur error :

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (390 ms @ 1/13/2016 8:37:44 PM)

like that.

3. then i put private key in pageant but still it is not working.
4. I have entered name & email under *TortoiseGit > Settings > Git*, bit
   still does not work.

alternatively: Is there any git GUI for gerrit, which works on Windows?

Comment: Try to set private key as described in this answer http://serverfault.com/a/198614. Also verify clone url on all required parts like username, port and so on, `ssh://<username>@<host>:29418/<project-name>`. And in case if it will not works you can try to use http instead of ssh if it is acceptable in your case.

Comment: Is [Gerrit/TortoiseGit tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/TortoiseGit_tutorial) help?